# "Segmentation fault: 11" when using Derelict and OpenGL

Tags: macos, opengl, sdl, d, dmd

I'm trying to run this on OSX 10.7:

```
/**
 * simple.d
 */

import std.stdio;
import derelict.sdl.sdl;
import derelict.sdl.macinit.SDLMain;
import derelict.opengl.gl;

pragma(lib, "/usr/local/src/Derelict2/lib/libDerelictUtil.a");
pragma(lib, "/usr/local/src/Derelict2/lib/libDerelictSDL.a");
pragma(lib, "/usr/local/src/Derelict2/lib/libDerelictGL.a");

int main(string[] args) {

    // Load Derelict
    writeln("Loading SDL...");
    DerelictSDL.load();

    // Initialise SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) == -1 ) {
        throw new Exception("SDL initialization failed");
    }

    // Enable Double Buffering
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

    // Set up the screen 
    SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 0, SDL_OPENGL);
    if (screen == null) {
        throw new Exception("Screen is null");
    }
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Simple", "Simple");

    // Print OpenGL and GLSL version
    writeln("Version Info");
    writeln("OpenGL:\t", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    writeln("GLSL:\t", glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));

    // Execute frame update
    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

    // Quit SDL; SDL_Quit() takes care of freeing the screen surface
    writeln("Quitting SDL...");
    SDL_Quit();

    writeln("Bye!");
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine, but when I try to run it I get:

```
$ ./simple 
Loading SDL...
Version Info
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Here's the thread output:

```
Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8376282a __kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8e965cfa _sigtramp + 26
2   ???                             000000000000000000 0 + 0
3   simple                          0x000000010d299db9 D2rt6dmain24mainUiPPaZi7runMainMFZv + 29
4   simple                          0x000000010d29976e D2rt6dmain24mainUiPPaZi7tryExecMFMDFZvZv + 38
5   simple                          0x000000010d299e06 D2rt6dmain24mainUiPPaZi6runAllMFZv + 58
6   simple                          0x000000010d29976e D2rt6dmain24mainUiPPaZi7tryExecMFMDFZvZv + 38
7   simple                          0x000000010d2996f9 main + 237
8   simple                          0x000000010d24a554 start + 52

Thread 1 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff837637e6 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff896b378a _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 923
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff896b231a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54
```

Now if I try to compile both Derelict and `simple.d` in 32bit mode (`-m32`) I get this output instead:

```
$ ./simple 
Loading SDL...
Version Info
Bus error: 10
```

Thread output:

```
Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x93107332 __kill + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x93106932 kill$UNIX2003 + 32
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x943f175e raise + 26
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9447d59b _sigtramp + 43
4   ???                             0xffffffff 0 + 4294967295
5   SDL                             0x01bb7108 SDL_Error + 275
6   simple                          0x000760ab D2rt6dmain24mainUiPPaZi7runMainMFZv + 23
7   simple                          0x00075a6c D2rt6dmain24mainUiPPaZi7tryExecMFMDFZvZv + 24
8   simple                          0x000760f3 D2rt6dmain24mainUiPPaZi6runAllMFZv + 59
9   simple                          0x00075a6c D2rt6dmain24mainUiPPaZi7tryExecMFMDFZvZv + 24
10  simple                          0x00075a0c main + 184
11  simple                          0x00035bb5 start + 53

Thread 1 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9310890a kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x96a74e10 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 969
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x96a7385f _dispatch_mgr_thread + 53
```

I've tried other `gl...` functions like `glClearColor()` and they yield the same results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't load the gl function pointers.

```
DerelictGL.load();
```